# Calculate from previous rows in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

i need to calculate pending_principal from the previous raw, is there any I can do this directly in SQL? I'm using BigQuery.

sample Data

| Date | Pending_principal |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1000000 |

i want to calculate pending_principal for next 5 days

and i expect that the result

| Date | Late_fee | Pending_principal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 0 | 1000000 |
| 2020-01-02 | 50000 | 1050000 |
| 2020-01-03 | 52500 | 1102500 |
| 2020-01-04 | 55125 | 1157625 |
| 2020-01-05 | 50000 | 1050000 |

The logic for late_fee

> late_fee=5% * previous row pending_principal

The logic for pending_principal

> pending_principal=previous pending_principal+late_fee

Is that possible in some way?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: please provide sample data and expect output (which I assume is the current table showcase in question, if true adding some text to indicate it is expect output).

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. How can late_fee depend on pending_principal and also pending_principal depend on late_fee? shouldn't everything in your able be 0? you need to show the raw data and your expected results.

Comment: Generally a recursive common table expression would do the trick in Oracle, Sql Server, DB2 etc.. This question and answer should point you in the right direction with respect to BigQuery:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890459/recursive-hierarchical-query-in-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this answer for the benefit of other SQL users. I'm not sure that BigQuery currently supports recursive common table expressions. I posted a link to some imperative looping syntax that might do the job in the question comments.

```
with recursive rcte as
(
    select 

        seed."date"
        , seed.fee
        , seed.pending

    from 

        (values  (cast('2020-01-01' as date), 0, 1000000)) as seed("date", fee, pending)

    union all
    
    select
    
        cast(rcte."date" + interval '1 day' as date) as "when"
        , cast(rcte.pending * 0.05 as int) as fee
        , cast(rcte.pending * 1.05 as int) as pending
    
    from
    
        rcte

    where
    
        rcte."date" < cast('2020-01-10' as date)
        
)

select

    *

from 

    rcte

;
```

[image: Sql and Output]