# Select an arbitrary parent of a row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose I have the following table

```
| `id` | `parent_id` |
|:------:| :-----:|
| 1    | `NULL` |
| 2    | 1 |
| 3    | 2 |
| 4    | 2 |
```

Each `parent_id` is a pointer to the parent `id`. How can I select the oldest parent_id of `id` 4 (which is 1, because its `parent_id` is `NULL`). In this example, id `2` and `1` is 1st and 2nd level parent of id `4`, respectively.

The number of parent a row can have is one, but its level is arbitrary.

The result should look like

| `id` | `oldest_parent_id` |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `NULL` |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: I am using Google BigQuery

Comment: You must use recursive queries, check out this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890459/recursive-hierarchical-query-in-bigquery

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to iterate trough your rows results.
Here is the usage sample to achieve it.

output table

```
CREATE TABLE `my-project-id.dataset.output_table`  (
  id INT64,
  oldest_parent_id INT64
);
```

query

```
DECLARE baseid int64;
DECLARE x int64;

FOR record IN
  (SELECT id,parentid from `my-project-id.dataset.table`)
DO 
  SET baseid = record.id;
  LOOP
    SET x = (SELECT parentid from `my-project-id.dataset.table` where id = baseid);
    IF x IS NULL THEN 
      LEAVE;
    ELSE 
      SET baseid = x;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  
  insert into `my-project-id.dataset.output_table` (id,oldest_parent_id) 
  select record.id, case when record.parentid is null then null else baseid end;

END FOR;
```

I have try different approaches to get this kind of output without loops but looking at the complexity, its not something you will get easily without getting your hands dirty. My recommendation for this kind of scenarios is to have an additional column that provides the key value already specified when a new row is inserted.

There is a lot of effort involve into get this specific id when it should not be like this.

To achieve above result I have follow below concepts:

- [For ... in](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#for-in)
- [Scripting Concepts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting-concepts)

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor, thanks for answering. I found a work around that does not need this, so haven't try what you guys suggested. Anyway, will upvote your answers