# Bigquery recursive SQL string concatenation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some table called `group_table` with hundreds of rows but looks something like this:

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 97 | b2 | null |
| 55 | ea | 54 |
| 56 | we | 54 |
| 57 | up | 53 |
| 58 | re | 53 |
| 54 | re | 53 |
| 53 | op | 97 |

I want to end up with a table like

| id | fullname |
| --- | --- |
| 55 | ea - re - op - b2 |
| 56 | we - re - op - b2 |

Where fullname is just the string concatening name with the delimeter " - ".

If we look at the 2nd table with id = 55 and fullname "ea - re - op - b2"... We can see the id of 55 correlates to "ea" and its parent_id = 54. The id = 54 is "re" and its parent_id = 53. the id = 53  is "op" where its parent_id = 97. Finally id = 97 is "b2" and it has no parent_id so its stops there.
Resulting in the string "ea - re - op - b2"

I was trying to figure out how to do this with BQ new recursive CTE https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#February_02_2022

But not getting the results I want. How would I get the results above??

Comment: Here the recursive CTE and the `loop` aproach are listed:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890459/recursive-hierarchical-query-in-bigquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query is based on solution from
[Mikhail Berlyant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59890459/recursive-hierarchical-query-in-bigquery) .

```
WITH recursive 

tbl as (
Select 97 id,   "b2" name,  null parent_id
UNION ALL SELECT 55 ,"ea",  54
UNION ALL SELECT 56 ,"we",  54
UNION ALL SELECT 57 ,"up",  53
UNION ALL SELECT 58 ,"re",  53
UNION ALL SELECT 54 ,"re",  53
UNION ALL SELECT 53 ,"op",  97
),
iterations as (
  select parent_id, id, name, 1 pos from tbl
  union all 
  select b.parent_id, a.id, b.name , pos + 1 
  from tbl a join iterations b
  on b.id = a.parent_id 
)

SELECT id, string_agg(cast(parent_id as string) order by pos) ,
array_to_string(array_agg(name order by pos),"-" )
from iterations 
group by 1
```